# Take Button's positon in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid

I have a Grid 5x4, where I place buttons from which later I will add Pictures. I need somehow to know where this button is located in this Grid, so I can replace added picture with this Plus image. Or if I choose multiple pictures, to know from which position to fill the grid with them.This is my grid and template:

```
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myItems" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,50,0,0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Click="Add_Picture">

                <Border Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="3" Padding="5">
                    <!-- <Canvas Margin="-1,-1,0,0" Width="90" Height="90" Name="cCanvas" MouseDown="cCanvas_MouseDown">-->
                    <Canvas Margin="-1,-1,0,0" Width="90" Height="90" Name="cCanvas">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>


                        <!-- <Grid Name="SquareSelectedIndicator" Visibility="{Binding  IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Hidden}" Width="30" Height="30" >-->

                    </Canvas>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="Black" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
            Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

For example here I want to take (x,y). Is this possible?
[image: grid]

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is to use (probably a two-level-deep) foreach on the grid's elements, where you can compare whether the element has a certain property (like name), and get the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties once it matches

Comment: So do you want to access the row and column index in the `Add_Picture` event handler?

Comment: Yes, exactly, for every button which calls the event. His initial coords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it didn´t produced the view you posted. All buttons layed on the same position above each other.

To get the view you posted I used a `UniformGrid` as ItemsPanel with a `Columns` value of 4.

```
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

So knowing this you could use the Add_Picture handler like this:

```
    private void Add_Picture(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
        if (clickedButton != null)
        {
            object displayedItem = clickedButton.DataContext;
            int index = this.myItems.Items.IndexOf(displayedItem);

            int x = index % 4;
            int y = index / 4;


            MessageBox.Show("x: " + x + " | y: " + y);
        }
    }
```

Let me know whether this suits your needs.